# How to measure the drain of a specific Lightning Network Channel that I own?

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-routing

We have seen that [the drain of a lightning network channel can be used to predict the failure rate of payments](https://blog.bitmex.com/price-of-anarchy-from-selfish-routing-strategies/) in this channel which correlates inversely with its reliability.

Assume my node `M` has a channel with another node `N` the drain can mathematically be defined by the fraction of traffic demand that goes from my node to the other node in comparison of all traffic.

```
                         # of routing requests from M-->N
drain = ------------------------------------------------------------------
        #of routing requests from M-->N + # of routing requests from N-->M
```

However in practice this seems very hard to measure as I will not see potential `# of routing requests from N-->M` in the case that `N` does not have enough liquidity on the channel to fulfill the routing request to `M`.

Are there any other workarounds how I could estimate / measure the drain value on a channel without having the necessity to talk to my peer?